# Get last modifed csv files from ftp server using python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to get yesterdays csv files generated from ftp server from multiple folders.
I can connect to ftp and get all csv files from a particular folder but not able to iterate the for loop to get all the files from sub folders.

```
FTP folder structure
/home/lan1/city/hyd/2022-03-14/hyd.csv
/home/lan1/city/knr/2022-03-14/knr.csv
/home/lan1/city/wgl/2022-03-14/wgl.csv

My code :

ftp = ftplib.FTP('192.00.000.00', 'lan1', 'G01d')
files = ftp.dir('/')
ftp.cwd('/home/lan1/city/')
PATH = '/home/lan1/city/*'
filematch = "*.csv"
target_dir = '/var/www/CSV'

import os
from glob import glob
for root, subdirectories, files in os.walk (PATH):
    for filename in ftp.nlst(filematch):
        target_file_name = os.path.join(target_dir,os.path.basename(filename))
        with open(target_file_name,'wb') as fhandle:
         ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' %filename, fhandle.write)
```

I am able to get csv files from /home/lan1/city if I put any csv file on it  but I need to get all the csv files from yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

not the cleanest code ever but it should work non the less:

```
import os
from ftplib import FTP
from datetime import date, timedelta

filenames = []
data = []
target_dir = '/var/www/CSV'


ftp = FTP('the.ftp.server.address', 'the.ftp.user', 'the.ftp.password')


def get_dirs_ftp(folder=None):
    if ftp.nlst(folder) is not None:  # Edit
        contents = ftp.nlst(folder)   # Edit
    folders = []
    yesterday = str(date.today() - timedelta(days=1))
    for item in contents:
        if "." not in item:
            # Check if folder has yesterdays date
            # /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if yesterday in item:
                folders.append(item)
    return folders


def get_all_dirs_ftp(folder=None):
    dirs = []
    new_dirs = get_dirs_ftp(folder)
    while len(new_dirs) > 0:
        for dir_ in new_dirs:
            dirs.append(dir_)

        old_dirs = new_dirs[:]
        new_dirs = []

        for dir_ in old_dirs:
            for new_dir in get_dirs_ftp(dir_):
                new_dirs.append(new_dir)
    dirs.sort()
    return dirs


def main():
    home = '/data/edi/kunden/da15620271'
    # get parent and child folders in directory
    # /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    all_dirs = get_all_dirs_ftp(home)

    # Loop through dirs
    # /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    for _dir in all_dirs:
        cwd = home + '/' + _dir
        ftp.cwd(cwd)
        for path in ftp.nlst():
            if os.path.basename(path).endswith('.csv'):
                print(cwd + path)
                # Download stuff here
                # /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

you will need to put the actual downloading part code in still in there though.

cheers

Comment: Dan,  Can you explain me what it should return and  let me know if this correct folder=None or should I giving the path '/home/lan1/city/

Comment: folder=None is correct all you need to do is set the home variable to '/home/lan1/city'. it will get passed into folder. and also ftp server, user and password. at the moment the function is printing the files it finds in the directories

Comment: Dan, I have tried your code , but it wont print  this line  print(cwd + path), I doubt if its  path the issue , it just does not give me any error. I am very much new to python, struggling to get the code working, Thanks for the support, much appreciated

Comment: received this error :

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "importcamdata.py", line 57, in <module>
    all_dirs = get_all_dirs_ftp()
  File "importcamdata.py", line 33, in get_all_dirs_ftp
    new_dirs = get_dirs_ftp(folder)
  File "importcamdata.py", line 17, in get_dirs_ftp
    contents = ftp.nlst(folder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 547, in nlst
    cmd = cmd + (' ' + arg)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Comment: Hey Kiran, i have updated the code line 14 to 15. should hopefully get rid of the traceback

Comment: I have tried that , still no change in error